# Loading Robot Resource files from Python package

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a number of teams working in Robot in separate repositories, and want to make available a set of common Python and Robot code to avoid duplication. I've pulled out the .py and .robot files that I want to package, have built the package (making sure that the .robot files are present in the .tar.gz), and have published it to our local artifactory. When I go to use these files in Robot tests, however, I can successfully use the .py files with the

`Library  package.module`

syntax.

However using Robot resources with the

`Resource  package.resource.robot`

syntax fails. Is there some way to include and utilize .robot resources in a python package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work as such:

```
Library         package.pythonmodule
Resource        package/robotfile.robot
```

Comment: It worked for me, despite the other answer saying it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Loading rf resource files from python packages is not supported by Robot Framework out of the box.

I wrote a blogpost about this few years ago: http://rasjani.github.io/2020/01/05/bundle-resources.html - and there's also a proof of concept library that's implementing the idea from the post here: https://github.com/rasjani/robotframework-importresource